Syfmony new Project directory . is not empty error
After cloning an existing git repo to install a new fresh Symfony I got the error Project directory not empty due to the existing .git folder I suspect. What is the recommended best practices/steps starting with an existing repo to install a symfony version ?
Steps to reproduce the error :
git clone myrepo
cd myrepo
symfony new . --webapp
--> You will get this error message :
Project directory . is not empty

first create your project in an non-existed folder (or an empty folder) and then add your remote to git.

After cloning a fresh symfony git repo, you, probably, have a compose.yaml ready.
If, so, i suggest to launch this command :
symfony composer update


The recommanded way is to create your project and then push it to some remote repository.
# This creates a folder named project-name
symfony new project-name

# Go inside this folder
cd project-name

# Add your remote repository
# When you create a repository on GitHub you can find this line in the main page of your repository
git remote add origin [address of the repository usually git@github.com:You/project-name.git]
git push --set-upstream origin main

You do the Symfony install first because it uses git to initialize the repository (and create the .git folder as well) to avoid you some commands at startup and you just have to push the init to the remote.

Yes but doesn't work if you need to use an already existing repo.
